# Teradata Studio Express: new install on Mac, not working

Tags: sql, macos, teradata

I just installed Teradata Express Studio (16.10.01) on MacOS Sierra 10.12.6, but when I try to open it I get the message 'An error has occurred'. The log file shows this (just first lines):

```
    !SESSION 2017-09-28 15:55:21.661 -----------------------------------------------
    eclipse.buildId=unknown
    java.version=9
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/KULMAK/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -keyring /Users/KULMAK/.eclipse_keyring

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 4 0 2017-09-28 15:55:26.460
!MESSAGE Exception occurred while creating new instance of component Component[
    name = ConnectionService
    activate = activate
    deactivate = deactivate
    modified = 
    configuration-policy = optional
    factory = null
    autoenable = true
    immediate = false
    implementation = com.teradata.datatools.connection.services.impl.ConnectionService
    state = Unsatisfied
    properties = 
    serviceFactory = false
    serviceInterface = [com.teradata.datatools.connection.services.interfaces.IConnectionService]
    references = null
    located in bundle = com.teradata.datatools.connection.services.definition_15.11.0.201708101349 [29]
] 
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3110)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3315)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.createInstance(ServiceComponent.java:493)
```

Prior to that I installed not-the-latest version of Java JDK 8 (Java 1.8), for compatibility reasons with other pieces of software - not that it matters, even if I install JDK 9, the issues remain the same.

Any ideas what could be causing issues?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved - it turns out there was a 'hidden' Java version 9 installed on my Mac that didn't appear in System Preferences (where you could see only Java 8), but became apparent after checking `java --version` in the terminal. After uninstalling Java 9 all my problems were solved.

Comment: I don't know what Teradata Express Studio is but the stack trace suggests that something is creating a custom class loader that is delegating directly to the boot loader. That is the only way that I can explain the NoClassDefFoundError. Hopefully someone can create a bug for this product (or Eclipse) so that they know to fix their issue with delegation.